# Display a LazyVGrid with Sections

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

I am trying to render a list of entities that are split into sections (think CoreData NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo).

I believe this solution (or very similar) used to be in the documentation. I have tried several ways of doing this, either I get the scrolling issue or pinnedViews won't pin.

I also asked this question in [Apple Dev Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733331), no takers so far.

This my solution, however it renders poorly. The ScrollView's content is far too long, scrolling is not fluid and may freeze.

```
    struct SectionsGridView: View {
        let sections: Sections<ListItemViewModel>
        let columns = [ GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: .cellSize)) ]
    
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: .gridSpacing, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                    ForEach(sections) { list in
                        Section(header: Text(list.title?.uppercased() ?? "error")) {
                            ForEach(list) { item in
                                GridCell().environmentObject(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private extension CGFloat {
        static let gridSpacing = 8.0
        static let cellSize = 100.0
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You haven't given enough code, as this won't build, and I am not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Please provide a minimal compilable code to reproduce. Generally I would say 1 - .environmentObject(item)` - there's probably no reason for that (it's just a propery most likely, or pssibly a binding, if it's changing); 2 - `ForEach(section)` looks weird. Did you mean to loop over some property of the section?; 3 - `let results: Sections<ListItemViewModel>` - not sure how you are filling these values, but since it's not a @State and inside a view, it may be reinitializing on every view redraw.

Comment: Thanks for your response, responding to your points:  1. Common pattern in Apple samples, passing the ViewModel in the environment.  2. Sections is a wrapper for `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` and implements `RandomAccessCollection` wrapping each entity in the declared ViewModel.  3. Passed as a parameter as unable to put generics into Environment.  I do not believe the issue is with the models as I use these patterns all over the App. The problems only start when trying to render the Sections in a Grid.  I will make a PoC with static data to see if this is reproducible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem.
The layout above works fine, the problem was with my Model.
Items in the collection had unstable identifiers.